# Why when adding to container is only the last item added?

Tags: extjs

In the following code, only the last item is added to col1 and col2.

```
initializeCharts: function() {
    var a = 0, col1Content = [], col2Content = [];
    // initialize the default charts from constant config data
    var col1 = this.getPerformanceOverviewpoolPanel().queryById('col1');
    var col2 = this.getPerformanceOverviewpoolPanel().queryById('col2');
    for(a = 0;a < DefaultMetrics.DEFAULT_METRICS.length;a++) {
        var chart = Ext.create('com.atlas.view.portlet.GraphiteChartPortlet', DefaultMetrics.DEFAULT_METRICS[a]);
        chart.title = DefaultMetrics.DEFAULT_METRICS[a].chartTitle;
        if(a % 2) {
            col2Content.push(chart);
        } else {
            col1Content.push(chart);
        }
    }
    col1.add(col1Content);
    col2.add(col2Content);
},
```

Comment: Can anyone help on this?

Comment: I should mention that I am using the Ext.app.Portlet feature.